# breath and breathe?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

> what is the phonological change that caused the voicing alternation / difference  between the words breath and breathe?

1. word-final devoicing
2. intervocalic voicing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the extent that it's reliable, [a section in the Wikipedia article about Middle English phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_phonology#Voiced_fricatives) says

> In Old English, [v], [ð], [z] were allophones of /f/, /θ/, /s/, respectively, occurring between vowels or voiced consonants.

There are many remnants of this today, without a general rule other than that the voiced version tends to be a verb: grass/graze, glass/glaze, breath/breathe, loose/lose, house(n.)/house(v.), bath/bathe, cloth/clothe, half/halve, calf/calve, life/live. For the nouns ending in /f/, the voicing is often retained before the plural ending -s: half/halves, calf/calves, roof/rooves, hoof/hooves, wife/wives, life/lives, wharf/wharves, loaf/loaves.

Comment: it is an intervocalic voicing, then, right?

Comment: That's my interpretation. And it goes way back: Dutch and German have similar unvoiced terminals that are voiced when followed by a vowel, including in their cognates for at least a few of these words.